# And then her head fell off

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I remember reading a compilation of children’s/bedtime/scary stories as a child, one of which was about a girl and a boy who eventually got married. Throughout the short story, she had a black ribbon tied around her neck, but refuses to tell her (eventual) husband what it is. On her deathbed she shows him what it's for; she pulls the bow loose and her head falls off.

What is the title of this book?

Comment: Could this be an Oz book, by chance?  I think I remember a character in Oz who had her head tied on -- but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, it's not set in Oz. It was set in 'the real world'.

Comment: I totally remember this story! I was going to guess Edgar Allen Poe, but he didn't write children's stories and I thought I remembered it was more modern. But, yeah, great story!

Comment: was this a story - we used to tell this as one of those interminable jokes that went on forever when we were kids - go figure

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've read it in either Grimm or Andersen, but now I can't find it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The story is The Green Ribbon, from the book [In a Dark, Dark Room and Other Scary Stories](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0064440907)

You can listen to an audio version of it on [Youtube here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3PIkV2anqk). There's also probably some different versions of the story that change the colour of the ribbon, depending on a few things.

Comment: Thanks very much! Had lots of fun just reading the reviews! :D

Answer (score 19):

This story makes the rounds of regional and children's ghost story collections in multiple versions featuring many different colored ribbons.  The original version is probably Washington Irving's "Adventure of a German Student" in which the band is black.  Trust your memory if you remember a different color, you undoubtably read a varient that did in fact feature the color you remember- tracking that specific version down, however, is a whole other issue.  *Tales for the Midnight Hour* by J. B. Stamper and Alvin Schwartz's *Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark* are two other children's collections with other versions.

Comment: +1 for noting that there are lots of folk-processed versions of this story, not just the one given in the other answer.