# Horror short story about a girl with red scarf

Tags: story-identification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [And then her head fell off](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/and-then-her-head-fell-off)

In the early 90s I read a children/young adult book of short horror stories. One of these stories was about a girl who wore a red scarf all the time.

> When the girl finally removes the scarf we learn that her head isn't attached.

Can anyone remember the name of this book?

Comment: The answer and the story identification were indeed duplicates, but our memories were vastly different. Glad to see the answer either way.

Comment: What's interesting is that in this question it was a "red scarf", in the linked question it was a "black ribbon", and in the accepted answer to the linked question it was a "green ribbon".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this -

"The Girl With the Green Ribbon Around her Neck" and it's in a children's book called "In a Dark Dark Room and Other Scary Stories." It's by Alvin Schwartz.

Comment: GREEN! Yes, that is totally it. Thank you very much.